# How to set and configure node.js with express to nginx reverse proxy on centos 6.4 virtualbox client?

Tags: node.js, express, centos, virtualbox

I am creating a development VM on my Windows 8.1 system using VirtualBox 4.3.4 and installed CentOS 6.4 as my VMServer. I installed NginX and Node.js with no problems. With little knowledge of administration I deleted the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` allowing all connections for development purpose only as of the moment (which will be changed later).

NginX is working fine, on my Windows host, and pointing the browser to `http://192.168.1.20` shows that the "Welcome to nginx on EPEL!" page is working.

Verifying that my node.js app is working correctly, I created a node app on my VMServer by running

```
[~]# express node_nginx_practice
[~]# cd node_nginx_practice && npm install
[~]# node app
```

Then, on my Windows host, point the URL to `http://192.168.1.20:3000`, the "Express default" page is running with no problem.

**The question is how could I set and configure node app to serve on nginx reverse-proxy?**

example: `http://192.168.1.20 //will point to Express default page`

I tried setting my nginx config in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` by following some tutorials on the web with no luck url still points to the NginX "Welcome to nginx on EPEL!" page.

Here's my `nginx.conf`

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user              nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }
}
```

I know I am missing something. Could someone point me to right direction?

### **EDIT ANSWER:**

Here's what i did to solve the issue in step by step! (Thanks to "C Blanchard")

edit the default NginX config file:

```
[~]# vim /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

and comment everything that is inside by prepending "#" to all of the lines.

restart NginX

```
[~]# /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Now the url points to the express page.

**EDIT UPDATE: Better solution.**

Open /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf find the location block and comment it by appending "#", and change specify the right location block pointing to node.js app. See code example below.

```
... 

#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

# Comment this block
#location / {
#    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
#    index  index.html index.htm;
#}

# This is the changed location block
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

error_page  404              /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

...
```

Now I remove the server block that I specified in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
# Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
# The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

# Remove from here
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
# Remove till here
```

}

Comment: Could you elaborate on "no luck"? What kind of errors are you seeing?

Comment: What i mean is the url still points to the NginX welcome page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directive in your configuration (shown below) loads the default server block. This is the reason why you see the nginx welcome page when you request localhost:80 on a newly installed instance of nginx

```
# Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
# The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

You'll find that nginx is already listening on port 80 for localhost so your requests may never reach your newly defined reverse-proxy

Try disabling your default nginx server by opening `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`, commenting out the server block there and then restarting nginx

Comment: Wew! That works! I've been working on this since yesterday. Thanks!